# React.lazy() vs React Loadable

Tags: reactjs, react-loadable

I was using [react-loadable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loadable) for some time for dynamic imports of my React components.

In the recent React release 16.6, the React team has included 
 `React.lazy()` which also does a dynamic import.

Is there any benefit in using the `react-loadable` package still, or is it time to move to the new React version?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**No**, React Loadable should not be used anymore, because it is not being maintained.

It used to be the recommended way for lazy loading when rendering on the server side, while React.lazy only works on the client side.

The React team now recommends another library for server side rendering.

Quote from the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html):

> Note: `React.lazy` and Suspense is not yet available for server-side rendering. If you want to do code-splitting in a server rendered app, we still recommend [Loadable Components](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components). It has a nice [guide for bundle splitting with server-side rendering](https://loadable-components.com/docs/server-side-rendering/).

Comment: React-loadable – very popular, but unmaintained library. Made code spitting a popular thing. Issues are closed, so there is no community around  and it is not compatible with Webpack v4+ and Babel v7+.

If you use it, it is recommended to migrate to @loadable/component.

Comment: Thanks for the update, when I wrote this answer in 2018, react-loadable was still maintained and recommended

Comment: Good one. I also converted my old `React Loadable` code into `React.lazy(component)` with `Suspense` wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing `SSR` you'll want to consider using `Loadable` instead of `React.lazy`, as suggested by the official `React.lazy` [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy):

> React.lazy and Suspense are not yet available for server-side rendering. If you want to do code-splitting in a server rendered app, we recommend Loadable Components. It has a nice guide for bundle splitting with server-side rendering.

Answer (score 1):

As answered above, react-loadable is not maintained, now people would use @loadable/component. The module support various pattern.

Here is a clear Comparison:

[image: comparison of React lazy and loadable/component]
For more detail, check [here](https://loadable-components.com/docs/loadable-vs-react-lazy/)